# Parola per dire “misurare a occhio” (corrispondente a “to eyeball”)

Tags: translation

Qual è una parola per esprimere il senso di “misurare a occhio”? Per chi sa l'inglese, ho in mente qualcosa di analogo a *to eyeball* come viene usato nella frase:

> The inspector eyeballed the room and guessed it to be twenty feet in length.

Comment: domenico, in genere è più apprezzato se uno mostra un minimo di sforzo nel trovare da solo la risposta prima di chiederla. Hai consultato un dizionario? Non ti ha soddisfatto quello che diceva?

Comment: @DaG Ho una mia traduzione ma preferisco non inserirla per non influenzare gli altri. La inserirò quando la domanda sarà risolta.

Comment: Hai il dubbio tra i due significati di “guardare intensamente” e “misurare a occhio”, per caso? Se sì, è una domanda più adatta a ELU.SE o a ELL.SE, dove i madrelingua inglese sapranno consigliarti meglio sul senso della parola in questo contesto. Se invece sai quale significato ti interessa, sarebbe meglio se lo dicessi e così potremmo aiutarti a esprimerlo al meglio in italiano.

Comment: ho inserito la frase di esempio per indicare il significato che mi interessa, che nelle tue alternative è "misurare ad occhio"

Comment: E allora forse aiuterebbe inserirlo nel testo della domanda. (Io personalmente l'avrei formulata qualcosa come «Qual è una parola per esprimere il senso xxx? Per chi sa l'inglese, ho in mente qualcosa di analogo a *to eyeball* come viene usata nella frase yyy».)

Comment: Fai pure le modifiche ritieni possano migliorare la chiarezza della domanda, nessun problema

Comment: Cerchi necessariamente una sola parola o potrebbe essere anche un'espressione con questo significato?

Comment: una singola parola (tipo "occhieggiare", ma non la sto proponendo come traduzione) sarebbe preferibile

Comment: A me non pare che *eyeball* voglia dire “misurare a occhio”, bensì “scrutare”. Il mio dizionario dice *look or stare at closely*. Quindi “L'ispettore scrutò la stanza e la stimò lunga circa sei metri”. Non mi fiderei a occhi chiusi di WordReference. Mi fiderei di più del Merriam-Webster: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eyeball

Comment: Però "eyeballing" come "misurare a occhio" è un uso invalso in inglese, oltre all'esempio preso da wordreference ne potrei fare diversi altri tratti da testi pubblicati, ecc.

Comment: @egreg: Giusto, m'ero dimenticato di specificarlo: prima di commentare e intervenire sulla domanda avevo consultato l'OED, che riporta come accezione 3: «*trans.* orig. U.S. To make a visual inspection or assessment of; to measure by sight alone, without the use of an instrument or other guide; to estimate by eye».

Answer (score 4):

Io renderei implicito quel "ad occhio", così

> L'ispettore osservò la stanza e la stimò essere lunga 20 piedi.

Oppure, usando il congiuntivo per la seconda frase, come ha fatto Dennis

> L'ispettore osservò la stanza e stimò che fosse lunga 6 metri.

A proposito, traduci pure i "piedi"

Comment: A proposito dei piedi, giustissimo! Nel 95% dei casi le unità di misura anglosassoni (piedi, libbre, gradi Fahrenheit etc.) vanno convertite in traduzione. (Occhio ovviamente a convertirle senza eccedere in precisione. Come ha fatto giustamente qui Agostino, va benissimo 6 metri, mentre sarebbe stato insensato 6,096 metri, a meno che non siano le specifiche tecniche di un apparecchio di precisione. Analogamente, in narrativa 10 miglia “sono” 15 o 20 chilometri, non 16,09.

Comment: Grazie DaG. A questo punto specifico che, a volte, le unità di misura americane, pur avendo lo stesso nome di quelle del Commonwealth (UK, Canada, Australia, etc.), indicano quantità diverse. Esempio: gallone US e gallone UK sono differenti.

Comment: Incidentalmente, il Commonwealth dovrebbe aver smesso di usare le unità imperiali dal 1965 (con l'eccezione delle miglia per limitare il costo di sostituire tutti i cartelli stradali). Credo siano in pratica ancora utilizzate dalla gente ma che stiano venendo lentamente sostituite dal sistema metrico decimale

Answer (score 2):

In questo contesto lo tradurrei come

```
misurare la stanza con una stima visiva.
```

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @Gabriele!

Answer (score 2):

Una traduzione un po' libera, ma io esprimerei l'esempio in italiano come

> L'ispettore esaminò la stanza ed a occhio stimò che fosse lunga venti piedi.

Personalmente tradurrei *eyeball* con *stimare a occhio*, ma ho preferito spostarlo come traduzione del secondo verbo perchè *stimò la stanza a occhio e la stimò a venti piedi* è orribile.

Answer (score 1):

Non conosco bene l'utilizzo di *eyeballed*, ma ho visto che tra i suoi sinonimi c'è ***scrutinize*** che secondo me, in questo caso, potrebbe essere tradotto con **esaminare**:

> L'ispettore esaminò la stanza e stimò che fosse lunga sei metri.

P.S. Quando i numeri non riguardano un discorso matematico è preferibile scriverli in lettere e non in cifre. [Dizionari Corriere](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/N/numeri.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

Si potrebbe anche usare:

"l’ispettore squadrò la stanza"

anche se squadrare è più comunemente usato per le persone